# AppSync error: Not Authorized to access listTodos on type Query

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've set up a basic app to test Amplify's [@auth](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/) rules. I have this simple graphql.schema:

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: public }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String
}

type Blog @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany
}
...
```

When I try to perform a simple list operation with AppSync, `Blog` succeeds, but `Todo` returns an error: `Not Authorized to access listTodos on type Query`

I have set my API (`amplify update api`) to use Cognito User Pools as the default auth, and to use API key as a secondary auth type. I would expect `allow: public` to permit access with the API key, but it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

For public users, [it is recommended](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#public-data-access) you use IAM to authorize unauthenticated users to run queries.

**Here is an example of @auth:**

```
type Todo
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete, read] }
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] }
    ]
  )
```

After changing the schema, go to the `CLI`, and write `amplify update auth` follow this image:

[image: AWS IAM CLI]

Comment: Sorry this answer is confusing. the first sentence does not read very well.
"IAM to authenticated unauthenticated users"